# Is it possible to change operator's bl_label on the fly?

Tags: python

I'd like to update the label of an operator when it's called. But this :

```
def execute(self,context):
    self.bl_label = "good night"
```

... apparently doesn't work if the bl_label property has already been defined. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manipulating an operator type once registered **isn't supported**. *****

Your options are:

- override the label when drawing the interface. eg:
  `layout.operator("some.op", text=label_override)`
- Modify the class, then re-register the operator
  (`unregister()` & `register()`)

Hint, if you want to do a conditional override, Python can do this by passing a dictionary...

```
keyword_args = {}
if some_test:
    keyword_args["text"] = label_override
layout.operator("some.op", **keyword_args)
```

---

******* (unless you modify the memory directly, which is possible but outside the scope of Blender/Python API).